# Visualise in a map featured from a related table in ArcGIS

Tags: arcgis-desktop, symbology, attribute-table, relates

I have an attribute table of a shapefile with some related attributes tables linked to the original table. I would like to show in the map through **Symbology > Categories > Unique values** one of the column from one of the related tables.

The column isn't visible in the Symbology "value field". I can only see the ones from the original table.

How can I make the related column appear ?

Comment: What program is this in? Can you see the attributes in the attribute table?

Comment: Which software? In some cases, after join both tables, you need to save the feature to a new file to apply symbology in the old relate table, now part of the attribute table.

Comment: It is in ArcGIS. I have the shapefile, I open the open attribute table and then I go to Related tables option and I chose the one relate table that I want and there I get the columns that I am interested in.

Comment: But when I go to Properties > Symbology > Categories, I cannot find the columns from the related tables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of "**Relating**" your external table, you should "**Join**" it. This way, you will be able to see the joined table values in your shapefile.

See [here a short vid](https://youtu.be/n1svGErNGYw) if needed.

Below some screens :

[image: Join table]

[image: Join table2]

Comment: Don't forget to tick the answer as accepted + upvote if it helped you :)